# Issue with union types and conditional types

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, union-types, conditional-types

I have following type declarations:

```
class MyGeneric<T> { }

type ReplaceType<T> = T extends Function ? T : MyGeneric<T> | T;
```

`ReplaceType<T>` should resolve to either `MyGeneric<T> | T` or `T` depending wheter `T` it is a function or not:

```
// Input type:    string
// Expected type: string | MyGeneric<string>
// Actual type:   string | MyGeneric<string>
type Test1 = ReplaceType<string>;

// Input type:    () => void
// Expected type: () => void
// Actual type:   () => void
type Test2 = ReplaceType<() => void>;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work correctly with `boolean` and union types:

```
// Input type:    boolean
// Expected type: boolean | MyGeneric<boolean>
// Actual type:   boolean | MyGeneric<true> | MyGeneric<false>
type Test3 = ReplaceType<boolean>;

// Input type:    "foo" | "bar"
// Expected type: "foo" | "bar" | MyGeneric<"foo" | "bar">
// Actual type:   "foo" | "bar" | MyGeneric<"foo"> | MyGeneric<"bar">
type Test4 = ReplaceType<"foo" | "bar">;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyGeneric%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ReplaceType%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20Function%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20MyGeneric%3CT%3E%20%7C%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Input%20type%3A%20%20%20%20string%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Expected%20type%3A%20string%20%7C%20MyGeneric%3Cstring%3E%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Actual%20type%3A%20%20%20string%20%7C%20MyGeneric%3Cstring%3E%0D%0Atype%20Test1%20%3D%20ReplaceType%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Input%20type%3A%20%20%20%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Expected%20type%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Actual%20type%3A%20%20%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0Atype%20Test2%20%3D%20ReplaceType%3C()%20%3D%3E%20void%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Input%20type%3A%20%20%20%20boolean%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Expected%20type%3A%20boolean%20%7C%20MyGeneric%3Cboolean%3E%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Actual%20type%3A%20%20%20boolean%20%7C%20MyGeneric%3Ctrue%3E%20%7C%20MyGeneric%3Cfalse%3E%0D%0Atype%20Test3%20%3D%20ReplaceType%3Cboolean%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Input%20type%3A%20%20%20%20%22foo%22%20%7C%20%22bar%22%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Expected%20type%3A%20%22foo%22%20%7C%20%22bar%22%20%7C%20MyGeneric%3C%22foo%22%20%7C%20%22bar%22%3E%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Actual%20type%3A%20%20%20%22foo%22%20%7C%20%22bar%22%20%7C%20MyGeneric%3C%22foo%22%3E%20%7C%20MyGeneric%3C%22bar%22%3E%0D%0Atype%20Test4%20%3D%20ReplaceType%3C%22foo%22%20%7C%20%22bar%22%3E%3B%0D%0A)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason `boolean` and unions are have similar behaviors is because the compiler sees `boolean` as a union of the literal types `true` and `false`, so `type boolean = true | false` (although this definition does not exist explicitly)

The reason for the behavior is that by design conditional type distribute over a union. This is the designed behavior and allows all sorts of powerful things to be implemented. You can read more on the topic [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/03/27/announcing-typescript-2-8/#conditional-types)

If you don't want conditionals to distribute over the union, you can use the type in a tuple (this will prevent the behavior)

```
class MyGeneric<T> { }

type ReplaceType<T> = [T] extends [Function] ? T : MyGeneric<T> | T;

// Input type:    string
// Expected type: string | MyGeneric<string>
// Actual type:   string | MyGeneric<string>
type Test1 = ReplaceType<string>;

// Input type:    () => void
// Expected type: () => void
// Actual type:   () => void
type Test2 = ReplaceType<() => void>;

// Input type:    boolean
// Expected type: boolean | MyGeneric<boolean>
// Actual type:   boolean | MyGeneric<boolean>
type Test3 = ReplaceType<boolean>;

// Input type:    "foo" | "bar"
// Expected type: "foo" | "bar" | MyGeneric<"foo" | "bar">
// Actual type:   "foo" | "bar" | MyGeneric<"foo" | "bar">
type Test4 = ReplaceType<"foo" | "bar">;
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I thought tuple types are always based on array types.

Comment: They are but the extends will check tuples members for compatibility just as they would for any other member of an object