# How to describe constraint using conditional type which is based on generic type?

Tags: typescript, dictionary, generics, conditional-types

I have a problem with typings in my code - union type constraint is generated instead of picking only one type from `ItemProperties` types dictionary. Is there any solution to make strict constraint for `props` property inside `ItemConfig` based on current `ItemType`?

P. S. wrapping `T` generic with tuple at `props` type declaration (as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51365569/3151214)) not solves the problem.

Simplified code example:

```js
enum ItemType {
  Dog = 1,
  Car = 2,
  Building = 3,
}

interface ItemProperties {
  [Item.Dog]: {
    name: string;
  };
  [Item.Car]: {
    power: number;
  };
}

interface ItemConfig<T extends ItemType = ItemType> {
  type: T;
  props: T extends keyof ItemProperties ? ItemProperties[T] : {};
}

const config: ItemConfig[] = [
  {
    type: ItemType.Dog,
    props: ...
  }
];
```

Expected `typeof props`:

```js
  { name: string }
```

Actual `typeof props`:

```js
  { name: string } | { power: number } | {}
```

Comment: I think the issue here is by declaring `config` to have type `ItemConfig[]` you are creating an array where every element has the same type for `T`. What you have now is `const config: ItemConfig<ItemType>[]` but what you want is `const config: (ItemConfig<ItemType.Dog> | ItemConfig<ItemType.Car> | ItemConfig<ItemType.Building>)[]` for every value of the enum.

Comment: Would this solution work for you? https://tsplay.dev/WJqVDm

Comment: Usually I use union for such cases. See here an [example](https://tsplay.dev/NBk8nm)

Comment: @captain-yossarian Mapped types and distributive conditionals both work. I usually use the latter if the source union is a type parameter, or if it doesn't extend `PropertyKey` (in which case you can't use a mapped type).

Comment: Oblosys and @captain-yossarian, thanks! Both solutions work!

Comment: @Oblosys, can you explain, please, how magic in your solution work? Conditional type can detach generic typing from common value for all array to individual value for each item of array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As remarked in the comments, the issue is that `ItemConfig` is equal to `{type: ItemType, props: {} | {name: string} | {power: number}}` whereas you'll want it to be a discriminating union `{type: ItemType.Dog, props: {name: string}} | {type: ItemType.Car, props: {power: number}} | ..`  to type the array element `props` correctly.

One way to create this union is by using a distributive conditional type ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)):

```
type ItemConfig<T = ItemType> = T extends ItemType ? {
  type: T;
  props: T extends keyof ItemProperties ? ItemProperties[T] : {};
} : never
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgLsCAVAngB2FA3gKClAEQHsBzKAXigEYAaPKAYQEMAnCqAJjvwCEwBLADYATfiDKUAzHQC%20OHGIQsAZkwDGmeIgAKLIhhZx%20wAM7Z6AbS3J0wAHTESAXQBc5-PhBMIwNybgsYiQA3PQyofhWCDYYdswsru4eaEQA7sAsbuAQAEYZEVDhOHI4cLaw0QxEIMr8JAA8SOzWqBgAfOxNwAAeCCDCZi3lAPxJZRhuSAVoemgmk1A9fQNQANbAKETKFTqzGUamUKPWuvr7xiYWSE5QblhFMrdQIMAAbhny45hIpnDNldVaiQcAB6EEeAB6w3kamq-igsJqdTc1iqSJIFhulAs9FwHigXxR0Va9kc3GSs3m2C8PjcAHJunS5PiwVAoWFyXiPISdjF7PFyfgZvoqVgUulMlAAOzMjys9n4GSc%20j4HlDWJklVQYVzO7ijJuGVa%20XQxU4JzBIA)

Because the `T` in the condition is a naked type parameter, `ItemConfig<ItemType.Dog | ItemType.Car | ItemType.Building>` distributes to `ItemConfig<ItemType.Dog> | ItemConfig<ItemType.Car> | ItemConfig<ItemType.Building>`, which is the desired union.

Alternatively (as captain-yossarian remarked), since `ItemType` extends `PropertyKey` (i.e. `string | number | symbol`), you can use a mapped type to create an object that has the constituents of the desired union as its values, and index that object to obtain the union:

```
type ItemConfig = {
  [T in ItemType]: {
    type: T,
    props: T extends keyof ItemProperties ? ItemProperties[T] : {}
  }
}[ItemType]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgLsCAVAngB2FA3gKClAEQHsBzKAXigEYAaPKAYQEMAnCqAJjvwCEwBLADYATfiDKUAzHQC%20OHGIQsAZkwDGmeIgAKLIhhZx%20wAM7Z6AbS3J0wAHTESAXQBc5-PhBMIwNybgsYiQA3PQyofhWCDYYdswsru4eaEQA7sAsbuAQAEYZEVDhOHI4cLaw0QxEIMr8EkkWSFBiFYioGIm4HlBlGG5I3Ml6aCb9UMAAHgggwmYA1sAoRMqtELr6GUamUAD8q%20sGWyaNTlBuWHL4cjJRbbZO8r2YSKZw7NZVNXU4APQ-HgA9HbyNTVfxQUFfEhuD7VWokCynSgWehdDxPGHRdr2RyDfBoYajbBeHxuADkEzJlw8fygQLCgzR%20Axq2xcVYeKgBP0RKwKXSmSgAHZqfhafSroz6MzbJi7rFcdKuYTzvyMm4RUrxcCrjgnMEgA)

This has the advantage that you don't need `ItemConfig` to have a generic parameter `T`, but it is limited to types that extend `PropertyKey` (otherwise you can't use it as a key in the mapped type).

Both approaches approaches yield the same `ItemConfig` union, which will allow the appropriate `props` type to be inferred for each array element:

```
const config: ItemConfig[] = [
  {
    type: ItemType.Dog,
    props: {name: 'x'}
    // type of props: {name: string}
  },
  {
    type: ItemType.Car,
    props: {power: 7}
    // type of props: {power: number}
  },
  {
    type: ItemType.Dog,
    props: {power: 7} // Type error
    // type of props: {name: string}
  }
];
```